# Screen recording from upload extension (NOT Streaming)

Tags: objective-c, xcode, broadcast, replaykit

I created an objc project which has the broadcast upload extension added to it. My aim is to send the CMSampleBufferRef which is returned in the extension to the main app.

I want to be able to change and modify the CMSampleBufferRefs in the main app. I cannot do much changes to the sample buffers in the extension as there is a 50MB memory limit.

My aim is to be able to create a video from the sample buffers.

Comment: What did you try?  I did it couple of times & IMHO, writing video frame to video file in broadcast extension wouldn't be a problem.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54485367/screen-recording-when-my-ios-app-is-in-background-with-replaykit/ can u help on this.?

Comment: @RyanB I have tried with broadcast upload extension. I cannot save my recorded video. Kindly help me this.